# Could not find bcrypt-3.1.7 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I have installed bcrypt using the command

**gem install bcrypt**

I can confirm that it is installed in my gem folder both local and @global and it is the correct version '3.1.7'. And... I have added the following line to my project:

**gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'**

When I run **bundle install** I get this...

**Your bundle is complete!**

However when I issue this command:

**rails generate devise:install**

I get the following...

```
Could not find bcrypt-3.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
user-pc:blog user$
```

I have even run:

**bundle list**

And I get a list of installed bundles and bcrypt 3.1.7 shows up!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem, it seems all I had to do was delete the `Gemfile.lock` file, and then re-run `bundle`!

You may also need to run `bundle exec rails generate devise:install` but it worked fine for me without the `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 13):

Killing the spring server worked for me.

```
$ ps aux | grep spring
46124   0.1  0.2  2479932  17964   ??  Ss   11:19AM   0:00.31 spring app    | Boomtownrack | started 33 secs ago | development mode
58978   0.0  0.1  2514736  11696 s002  S     3:30PM   0:00.43 spring server | Boomtownrack | started 12 hours ago
46130   0.0  0.0  2432784    628 s002  S+   11:19AM   0:00.00 grep spring

$ kill 58978
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `bundle update` or `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`